# Literature in table of contents but wrong position

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I am using the code on the left of the picture and what it gives me is on the right. But what I 'd like to accomplish is something like **A. Glossary B. References C. Appendix**

[image: Transition]

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: In your other two questions you added a minimum working example...

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.